# example for torsion-free but not cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am asked to provide an example for torsion-free but not a cyclic group. Is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ an example?

Comment: Sure. Or the rationals under addition. Or the reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All [free abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group) are torsion-free, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117547/a-free-abelian-group-is-torsion-free). Of course, free ableian groups of rank $>1$ are not cyclic. This generalizes your example. On the other hand, all finitely generated torsion-free abelian groups are free abelian.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One more question, the converse is not true(torsion free is not all free abelian group), right? As you mentioned in the last sentence, counterexample can be considered among those not finitely generated torsion-free abelian groups. Is $\mathbb{Z}^{\infty}$ a such example(torsion-free but not free abelian group)?

Comment: Yes, $\prod_{i\ge 0} \mathbb{Z}$ is not free abelian, but $\mathbb{Q}$ is an easier example of a torsion-free group which is not free abelian - see above.

Comment: OK, thank you so much for your help!